# Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:43184)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

While trying to run pyspark in a jupyter notebook, I often end up with this common connection error. Restarting kernel or even my putty terminal doesn't work. I understand the cause is somewhere around the fact that java and pyspark are referring two different servers. How do I resolve this to ensure server match?

```
 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension                                                                                        .js?v=20190912013347 (127.0.0.1) 5.23ms referer=http://localhost:12345/notebooks                                                                                        /QuadID%20prepare%20indexes.ipynb
[I 01:34:06.143 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 835a6227-4699-49fd-b954-c627657b863                                                                                        c
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/home/e079494/log4j                                                                                        .properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/e079494/log4j.properties (No such file or d                                                                                        irectory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection                                                                                        .java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLCon                                                                                        nection.java:188)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurato                                                                                        r.java:557)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionCon                                                                                        verter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:6                                                                                        6)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogF                                                                                        actory.java:156)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogF                                                                                        actory.java:132)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSu                                                                                        bmit.scala:315)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [file:/home/e079494/log4j.properties].
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLeve                                                                                        l(newLevel).
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Att                                                                                        empting port 4041.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Att                                                                                        empting port 4042.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Att                                                                                        empting port 4043.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4043. Att                                                                                        empting port 4044.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4044. Att                                                                                        empting port 4045.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4045. Att                                                                                        empting port 4046.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4046. Att                                                                                        empting port 4047.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4047. Att                                                                                        empting port 4048.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4048. Att                                                                                        empting port 4049.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4049. Att                                                                                        empting port 4050.
19/09/12 01:34:08 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4050. Att                                                                                        empting port 4051.
19/09/12 01:34:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4051. Att                                                                                        empting port 4052.
19/09/12 01:34:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4052. Att                                                                                        empting port 4053.
19/09/12 01:34:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4053. Att                                                                                        empting port 4054.
19/09/12 01:34:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4054. Att                                                                                        empting port 4055.
19/09/12 01:34:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4055. Att                                                                                        empting port 4056.
19/09/12 01:34:09 ERROR SparkUI: Failed to bind SparkUI
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Service 'SparkUI' failed after 1                                                                                        6 retries (starting from 4040)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port                                                                                         for the service 'SparkUI' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an availab                                                                                        le port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:                                                                                        223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.j                                                                                        ava:317)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Abstr                                                                                        actNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnecto                                                                                        r.java:235)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abstra                                                                                        ctLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.org$apache$spark$ui$JettyUtils$$newCo                                                                                        nnector$1(JettyUtils.scala:333)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.org$apache$spark$ui$JettyUtils$$httpC                                                                                        onnect$1(JettyUtils.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JettyUtils.scala:368)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$7.apply(JettyUtils.scala:368)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$                                                                                        sp(Utils.scala:2237)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2229)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.startJettyServer(JettyUtils.scala:368                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SparkContext.scala:46                                                                                        3)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SparkContext.scala:46                                                                                        3)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:463)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.sc                                                                                        ala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct                                                                                        orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC                                                                                        onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand                                                                                        .java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1035, in send_c                                                                                        ommand
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 883, in send_co                                                                                        mmand
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1040, in send_c                                                                                        ommand
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java se                                                                                        rver (127.0.0.1:32844)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    .getOrCreate()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call                                                                                        __
    answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 327, in get_return_                                                                                        value
    format(target_id, ".", name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.a                                                                                        pi.java.JavaSparkContext

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 827, in _get_co                                                                                        nnection
    connection = self.deque.pop()
IndexError: pop from an empty deque

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/s                                                                                        park2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 963, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file /opt/cloude                                                                                        ra/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.232957/lib/spark2/python/pyspar                                                                                        k/shell.py:
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have restarted your kernel and doesn't fix the issue, you may want to close down your browser and re-launch it. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Uninstall and Install java 8 (Spark is not compatible with Java 9 or newer)
2. While installing Java 8, make sure there is no space in folder name where you installing ( in my case I set destination folder as c:\JavaJdk)
3. Download winutils.exe and move that to c:\winutils\bin folder.
4. Create another folder directory c:\tmp\hive
5. Cd into c:\winutils\bin run the command "winutils.exe chmod 777 c:\tmp\hive"
6. Open the c:\spark\conf folder, and make sure “File Name Extensions” is checked in the “view” tab of Windows Explorer. Rename the log4j.properties.template file to log4j.properties. Edit this file (using Wordpad or something similar) and change the error level from INFO to ERROR for log4j.rootCategory
7. Check you “Environment Variables”

hope if you follow above steps, you won't see the same error message.